# Как в Django добавить CKEditor в форму на странице?

Tags: django

Всем привет.

В интернете решения не нашел.

В админке CKEditor работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в форме его нет:

[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]

> **models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Заголовок')
    post_content = RichTextField(max_length=450000, verbose_name='Содержание', default='test')
```

> **forms.py**

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['cat'].empty_label = 'категория не выбрана'

    captcha = CaptchaField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['post_title', 'post_content']

    def clean_post_title(self):
        post_title = self.cleaned_data['post_title']
        if len(post_title) >= 250:
            raise ValidationError('Длина превышает 250 символов')

        return post_title
```

> **views.py**

```
class FormAdd(View):

    def get(self, request):
        form = PostForm
        return render(request, 'sitelogic/addpost.html', context={'form': form})

        def post(self, request):
        request_keep = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if request_keep.is_valid():
            request_keep.save()
            return redirect('home_page')
        return render(request, 'sitelogic/addpost.html', context={'form': request_keep})
```

> **addpost.html**

```
    <form action="{% url 'add_post' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">добавить</button>
    </form>
```

P.S: Ссылка на CKEditor https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `ModelForm`:

```
post_content = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())
```

В `templates`:

```
<form>
    {{ myform.media }}
    {{ myform.as_p }}
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Невероятно, так просто и все работает. большое спасибо :)